# How to write complex Kotlin for loop

Tags: kotlin

It's easy to write simple loops like `for (i in 0..10)`, but how to write more complex loops like:

```
for (byte i = 1 << 7; i != 0; i >>= 1)
```

or

```
for (byte i = 0x01; i != 0; i <<= 1)
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not what a `for` loop is for in Kotlin. You can use a normal `while` statement instead.

```
var i: Int = 1 shl 7
while (i != 0) {
    // . . .
    i = i shr 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't like having a `var` and are ok with using a `Sequence`, you could also use something like [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) instead, e.g.:

```
generateSequence(1 shl 7) {
  it shr 1
}
    .takeWhile { it != 0 }
    .forEach { ... }

// or: generateSequence(1 shl 7) { (it shr 1).takeIf { it != 0 } }.forEach { ... }
```

Otherwise Michaels answer about using `while` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I like avoiding `var`s and find myself using that style more and more (and sadly Java is quite bad at it). However, I guess for simple loops I will continue the old-fashioned way.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I tend to use it nearly everywhere now... I really like that seed, next-value-function and loop-termination-condition are so near by each other... (maybe I also just saw `for (seed; next-value-function; loop-termination-condition)`-statements too often, so that I think I need this construct ;-)